# add Select data by php

Tags: php

```
<select class="form-control" name="city">
              <option value="0">Filter by City</option>
              <?php
              try {
                  $pdo = new PDO(DBCONNSTRING,DBUSER,DBPASS);
                  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "select geocities.AsciiName from geocities INNER JOIN travelimagedetails ON geocities.GeoNameID = travelimagedetails.CityCode group by geocities.GeoNameID";
                 $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['AsciiName'].'>';
                    echo $row['AsciiName'].'</option>';
                   }
                  $pdo = null;
              }
               catch (PDOException $e) {
                   die( $e->getMessage() );
              }
              ?>
           </select>
          </div>
```

[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkf6.png)

When I remove the first PHP tag everything works well
But when I add it everything fall

Comment: You're missing a closing quote. `echo '<option value="'.$row['AsciiName'].'>';` should be `echo '<option value="'.$row['AsciiName'].'">';`

Comment: Its work thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try the frequent use of PHP tags, it will solve your problem of finding it difficult to read code clearly

```
<select class="form-control" name="city">
              <option value="0">Filter by City</option>
              <?php
              try {
                  $pdo = new PDO(DBCONNSTRING,DBUSER,DBPASS);
                  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "select geocities.AsciiName from geocities INNER JOIN travelimagedetails ON geocities.GeoNameID = travelimagedetails.CityCode group by geocities.GeoNameID";
                 $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
               ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $row['AsciiName']?>"> <?php echo $row['AsciiName']?> </option>;
                <?php
                   }
                  $pdo = null;
              }
               catch (PDOException $e) {
                   die( $e->getMessage() );
              }
              ?>
           </select>
```

You should be using Prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

**Prepared Statement**

```
<select class="form-control" name="city">
              <option value="0">Filter by City</option>
              <?php
              try {
                  $pdo = new PDO(DBCONNSTRING,DBUSER,DBPASS);
                  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "select geocities.AsciiName from geocities INNER JOIN travelimagedetails ON geocities.GeoNameID = travelimagedetails.CityCode group by geocities.GeoNameID";
                // check if prepare statement worked well
                if (!$query = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                   // error message
                }  else{ // successful prepared statement
                    //checking if query executed well
                    if ($query->execute()) {
                        $result = $query->fetchAll();
                    }
                }
                // checking if $result is alive
                if (isset($result)) {
                   foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['AsciiName']?>"> <?php echo $row['AsciiName']?> </option>;
                <?php //$pdo = null;
              } // end foreach
            } // end check result if
        } // end Try
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                   die( $e->getMessage() );
              }
              ?>
           </select>
```

Comment: The problem is only a missing quote.

Comment: John Conde yes, That's what's wrong but the code can still be improved. And besides, prepared statement is better to prevent SQL injection.